# Are badges on SO not working anymore?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, badges

Well, I've only just noticed that after posting [a somewhat popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170215/redirect-users-based-on-server-traffic-with-php/4170280#4170280) (7ups question / 7ups + accept answer) I wasn't awarded any badges at all. Having looked at the badge list, I think that, if I'm not mistaken, I should've been awarded the following:

- Good answer (answer score of 25 or more)
- Nice answer
- Guru (accepted answer and score of 40 or more)

Just to clarify, the score of the answer was 80.

That's probably it. Is something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Score` refers to the number of up votes received not the reputation earned.

So you would need at least another 3 up votes before receiving the Nice Answer badge - which requires 10 up votes.

Comment: oh! Now I get it, sounds reasonable that guru, requires more than 4 upvotes. Thank you!